# how to use array_push php

Tags: php, json, array-push

Function result is not expected. I would like json encode type records

```
function aTree($array, $treeList)
{

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
            $valueX = ltrim($value["link"]["link_x"], "node/");
            $valueY = $value["link"]["link_y"];

            echo array_push($value, $valueX, $valueY);
            if (!empty($value["below"])) {
                echo "------\n";
                aTree($value["below"]);
                echo "------\n\n";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

I expect results

```
[{"link_x":"link_y"},{"link_x":"link_y"} ... ]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, please give an example input array for us to understand... And the documentation of `array_push()` clearly states that the return value is a integer, I doubt you want to cho` that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
array_push($value, array($valueX => $valueY));
```

instead of

```
echo array_push($value, $valueX, $valueY);
```

and finally (after your `foreach` loop) you have to call

```
echo json_encode($value);
```

Comment: because result is key => value

Comment: Could you please show me the result, when you apply the code changes of my answer?